# Howto define distinct xcconfig parameters in Cocoapod subspecs?

Tags: objective-c, configuration-management, cocoapods, xcconfig

I've developed an iOS project that is a class library dealing with different servers. Only one server is needed per application in which the library is used. The server type is configurable through a preprocessor definition at compile time.

In the podspec of my library, I defined various subspecs for each server like this:

```
s.name = "ServerLib"
[...]
s.subspec 'ServerA' do |a|
    a.source_files = 'Classes/A/**/*.{h,m}'
    a.xcconfig = { "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" => "$(inherited) ServerA=1" }
end

s.subspec 'ServerB' do |b|
    b.source_files = 'Classes/B/**/*.{h,m}'
    b.xcconfig = { "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" => "$(inherited) ServerB=1" }
end
```

My application is a multi-customer app with one target per customer. Each customer uses a specific server from the library project. So, my Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'MyCore'
pod '3rdPartyLib'

target :'Customer1', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'ServerLib/ServerA'
end

target :'Customer2', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'ServerLib/ServerB'
end
```

What the `pod install` script does, is merging ALL flags defined in the subspecs into one value in every pod-customerN.xcconfig file

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) 3RD_PARTY_FLAGS $(inherited) ServerA=1 $(inherited) ServerB=1
```

Any suggestions how to circumvent this wrong(?) behavior of Cocoapods? As far as I understand the documentation, subspec properties should inherit only from its parent specs not same-level subspecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround, maybe not that elegant:

Since `pod install` merges all compiler flags into one, I had to remove the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` from the library's `podspec` file. But without this definition, my library does not build.

In Xcode this can be fixed easily by adding the definition to each library's target. But when I use my library in an application, the Pods project is generated out of the Podspec which doesn't include the required flag.

The solution is to use the `post_install` hook in the application's Podfile to manipulate the generated xcconfig of the Pods project.

```
post_install do |installer|

    file_names = ['./Pods/Pods-ServerA.xcconfig',
                  './Pods/Pods-ServerB.xcconfig']

    # rename existing pre-processor definitions
    file_names.each do |file_name|
        text = File.read(file_name)
        File.open(file_name, 'w') { |f| f.puts text.gsub(/GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS/, "GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_SHARED")}
    end

    # merge existing and required definition for ServerA
    File.open('./Pods/Pods-ServerA.xcconfig', 'a') { |f|
        f.puts "\nGCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=$(GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_SHARED) ServerA=1"
    }

    # merge existing and required definition for ServerB
    File.open('./Pods/Pods-ServerB.xcconfig', 'b') { |f|
        f.puts "\nGCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=$(GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_SHARED) ServerB=1"
    }

end
```

The code is a bit verbose since I'm not familiar with Ruby but it works. It should be easily possible to automate this renaming-append process as long as variable and library follow a naming scheme.